# How do you explain the lemma for actual definition of integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definite-integrals

So the lemma states that Let $P$ and $Q$ be partition of $[a,b]$ such that $P \subseteq Q$. Then $$L_f(P) \le L_f(Q) \le U_f(Q)\le U_f(P) $$

But how do you define $P \subseteq Q$? Is it the area or interval? And how does the lemma visualize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partition is a finite subset $\{x_0,\dots,x_n\}\subset[a,b]$: $a = x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n = b$. $P\subset Q$ is simply the inclusion of sets. For the geomereic idea of refinement, see http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtd/1/txe3da1a.htm.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you may take a partition $P =\{a = t_0 < \ldots < t_n = b\}$ and add one extra point $p$, such that $t_{i-1} < p < t_i$, for some $i = 0,1 \ldots, n$. Then $Q = P \cup \{p\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$ and $P \subseteq Q$.

[image]
This process can be repeated.